# ZoomIn Keyboard Controls

Tags: qt

How to remove the Shift key from Qt Keypress event(ie. Ctrl + Shift + +) for ZoomIn command. More details are added below,

QKeySequence keys_zoomin(QKeySequence::ZoomIn);

Comment: `QKeySequence::ZoomIn` is `Ctrl` and `+` combination, you can access the `+` key on num pad. To use `=` key try `QKeySequence("Ctrl+=")`.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm using Qt 6.6 on Windows, Ctrl/+ doesn't work for for ZoomIn but Ctrl/Shift/+ does work.